# avoid navigation from the browser url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project in which I have several sections. the user can only interact with my application through the internal navigation. but if the user writes something in the url, and reloads the page, I would like to be redirected to some state or failing to allow it. how can I do this?

I have this in my code. and in my real project I do validation depending on the state I receive, but in this case I do not know how to detect when navigating directly when writing the url from the browser navigation bar.

```
$transitions.onSuccess({ }, trans => {

})
```

Comment: You could just define all your states to not have a URL.

Comment: I need show the url

Answer (score 0):

There's an http header that every browser sends. It is the [Referrer Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) but it's the server ho check it.

Anyway could you explain why you do not want the user to use the url to move around the application?

From a security perspective block this is not a good solution, you must use something like this https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/08/handling-basic-route-authorization-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

This might work. It's rather hard to test URL routing on plunkr.

Inject `$urlService` somewhere (such as a `.run()` block) and disable URL navigation.

```
.run(function($urlService) {
    $urlService.deferIntercept();
});
```

Comment: it not works for me. angularRoutingApp.run(function($rootScope,$state,$location,$transitions,$urlService)
{

    $urlService.deferIntercept();  ...